# UFS as a shared partition between Linux and Mac OS?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, partitioning, filesystems, ufs

I see that (i) you can't boot from a UFS disk with Snow Leopard, and (ii) Disk Utility doesn't allow UFS partitions to be created.

Why the aloofness? Is UFS still a reasonable choice of shared partition between Linux and Mac OS?

Comment: Apple probably sees no need to support something like that anymore. See also: Java, ZFS.

Comment: Don't forget Flash. Oh wait, Apple already did.

Comment: @Daniel: Well, Java/ZFS/Flash are complex technologies whose evolution is determined by competitors.  UFS is an old, open, fixed technology that is an integral part of the FreeBSD that Darwin is based on.  The support costs don't seem all that high to me.  The issue is that there are no good choices of filesystem from what Disk Utility offers that are reasonable partitions to share with Linux...

Comment: Apple is incredibly lazy where their desktop OS is concerned now. They make minimal to no effort to provide backward compatibility and alternative filesystems. NTFS is read-only, even in Lion. They're just too busy with mobile devices to devote resources to the Mac now; the Intel switch also indicates that they wanted to shift R&D elsewhere, since this way Intel has been and continues to do most of the hardware-related work for them now.